# How to find page number by row in primeng datatable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using primeng datatable in multiple tabs, so for example, I have three tabs and each has a data table, all columns in my table have a search filter.

User filters the table to get some column there are about 3000 columns in the table, an then user switch tabs.

There is my problem when the user goes back to the first table, the first page is loaded, I need somehow **select the row was previously found**.

I use [(selection)] to preserve the selection

```
<p-treeTable [value]="files1" [columns]="data" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode" >
```

Is there a way to **find page number by row**?

Comment: did you get a chance to look into this. if you are using Version 7 of Primeng
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/state

Comment: @DirtyMind that exactly what I need !!! thank you!